# Calculation of an optimal variational distribution for covariance parameters in a Bayesian graphical lasso model

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, variational-bayes, laplace-distribution, variational-inference

**Context**:

I am considering here a variational Bayesian framework where I need to calculate the optimal variational distribution for some covariance parameters.

Formally the model can be expressed as:

$$P(W|X,\beta, \Sigma^{-1})P(\Sigma^{-1}|\lambda)$$

where $W$ is a matrix of outcomes of size $NJ$ where $N$ is the sample size and $J$ the number of outcomes. $X$ a matrix of $(K+1)$ covariates for the same $N$ individuals. $\beta$ is a $(K+1)J$ matrix of covariate effects. Finally we want to estimate the posterior for $\Sigma$ the precision matrix accross the $J$ outcomes.

Since we are in a Bayesian graphical lasso model, we assume $P(W|X,\beta, \Sigma^{-1}) \sim N(X\beta, \Sigma^{-1})$ and the covariance parameters (off diagonal elements of $\Sigma^{-1}$) $s_{jj'} \sim Laplace(0, \lambda^{-1}), \forall j'\neq j$.

Using standard results from variational inference we can determine the optimal variational distribution for covariance parameters with:

$$
q^*(s_{jj'}) = E_{-s_{jj'}}(\log(P(W|X,\beta, \Sigma^{-1})P(\Sigma^{-1}|\lambda)))
$$

where $E_{-s_{jj'}}$ is the expectation taking over all parameters except $s{jj'}$.

**What I did**:

Following [https://www.math.wustl.edu/~sawyer/handouts/multivar.pdf](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Esawyer/handouts/multivar.pdf) the model for $P(W|X,\beta, \Sigma^{-1})$ was rewritten as a sum over individuals (i), covariates (k) and outcomes (j & j'). Also, using the correspondence between a centered Laplace distribution and the exponential we obtain:

$$\prod_j \prod_{j'} \lambda \exp\{ -\lambda s_{jj'}\} \prod_i \prod_j \prod_{j'} \prod_k \frac{s_{jj'}}{\sqrt(2\pi)} \exp\{-\frac{1}{2}s_{jj'}(W_{ij} - X_{ik}\beta_{kj})(W_{ij'} - X_{ik}\beta_{kj'})\} $$

Applying the log while keeping only terms involving $s_{jj'}$ and taking the expectation the optimal $q^*(s_{jj'})$ is equal to:

$$
-s_{jj'}(E(\lambda) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \sum_k (W_{ij} - X_{ik}E(\beta_{kj}))(W_{ij'} - X_{ik}E(\beta_{kj'})))
$$

which is proportional to a centered Laplace with scale parameter $\delta = \frac{1}{E(\lambda) + 0.5*\sum_i\sum_k(W_{ij} - X_{ik}E(\beta_{kj}))(W_{ij'} - X_{ik}E(\beta_{kj'}))}$

**IMPORTANT**: This result is expected since the prior over covariance parameters is from the exponential family. Indeed, assuming a "mean-field" factorization we know that the optimal q is from the same distribution as the prior.

**My Problem**:

However my problem here is that, due to the cross product between $j\&j'$, $\delta$ may be negative. Leading to errors when computing the ELBO. Are my calculations correct or I did something wrong?

Any insights are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after bunch of readings on the topic I finally came out with a solution for my problem. I don't know if someone else would be interested in this topic, I will provide an answer to my own question though.

From my understanding some of Bayesian penalized models (LASSO and Horseshoe for example) suppose a non normal prior on the beta coefficients, making the posterior calculation quiet tricky. However, and as originally proposed by Gelman in a Bayesian context and other authors after him, this kind of distributions can be rewrite as a mixture of gaussian. This hierarchical rewriting makes the prior a conjugate, hence facilitating MCMC runs or variational Bayes derivations. Here a great paper on this topic: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340006729_A_practical_tutorial_on_Variational_Bayes

Regarding my question about covariance parameters my initial understanding was that the prior has to be from exponential family in order to derive analytical solutions for the optimal variational distribution. In fact, the prior has to be conjugate. So, neither the original Laplace prior nor the Gaussian mixture are conjugate priors, making variational bayes closed-form solutions for the covariance parameters impossible.

I finally decided to use a Wishart distribution for the covariance matrix using ideas from this paper to shrink on-diagonal and off-diagonal elements: DOI:10.1214/13-BA815.

I do not know if it is the best way to approach sparse covariance matrix but I will not need any sort of approximations, used in G-Wishart or any kind of non-conjugate priors.

Any ideas are welcome to discuss my choices.