# How to express a Laplace Distribution as a mixture of an exponential and Normal Distribution

Tags: variational-bayes

I have seen in different Bayesian papers that a common trick to rewrite a Laplace distribution is to use the fact that the distribution can be expressed as a mixture of an exponential and a Gaussian distribution. While this result is used in the Bayesian Lasso paper ([https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring09/other-readings/park-casella.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring09/other-readings/park-casella.pdf)) I have some trouble to grasp the general result. The authors mentioned the original paper of Andrews and Mallows 1974. I would like to use this result for computing some optimal distributions in a variational bayes context but I am stuck with the absolute value arising in the distribution. I have already posted a question here without answer so far : [Calculation of an optimal variational distribution for covariance parameters in a Bayesian graphical lasso model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622791/calculation-of-an-optimal-variational-distribution-for-covariance-parameters-in)

Any help will be welcome